# Difference in watch properties vs $watch method in created event (Vue)

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Is there any difference in watch properties vs $watch method in Vue? For example, I'm trying to understand why the Author use the $watch event instead of watch property in the code below.

```
 created () {
    const routes = this.mainMenu.find(item => item.path === '/')
    this.menus = (routes && routes.children) || []
    // 处理侧栏收起状态
    this.$watch('collapsed', () => {
      this.$store.commit(SIDEBAR_TYPE, this.collapsed)
    })
    this.$watch('isMobile', () => {
      this.$store.commit(TOGGLE_MOBILE_TYPE, this.isMobile)
    })
  },
```

If say I move the $watch as below, is there any difference?

```
 watch: {
    isMobile : function(value) {
       this.$store.commit(TOGGLE_MOBILE_TYPE, value)
    },
    collapsed : function(value) {
       this.$store.commit(SIDEBAR_TYPE, value)
    }
 },
 created () {
 }
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `watch` options uses `this.$watch` method under the hood, so it's basically the same.

The only difference is that `this.$watch` returns a function you can call to stop the watcher:

```js
const queryWatcher = this.$watch('$route.query', doSomethingFunction)

...

queryWatcher() // Stop the watcher
```

There's no point of using `this.$watch` is you don't need that stop function so you can safely move them to the `watch` option property.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the explanation. I thought there is some purpose of putting the watch on created event instead of use it in watch property earlier. It is clear now.   Thanks

Comment: Well sometimes it's just because people misunderstand some concepts. As long as it works, they won't try to do it another way. It's good that you're questionning yourself :)